# XSLT transformation with keyed Param

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a piece of xslt file which looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Request">
    <Instrument>
        <IdentifierType>
                 <xsl:value-of select="IDContext"/>
        </IdentifierType>
        <Identifier>
                 <xsl:value-of select="Identifier"/>
        </Identifier>
        <UserDefinedIdentifier>
                 <xsl:value-of select="UserDefinedIdentifier"/>
        </UserDefinedIdentifier>
        <xsl:if test="Param[@Key='Exchange']">
                 <Exchange>
                           <xsl:value-of select="Param[@Key='Exchange']"/>
                 </Exchange>
        </xsl:if>
    </Instrument>
</xsl:template>
```

And one input xml piece look like this:

```
<Request>
    <Identifier>XXX</Identifier>
    <IDContext>ISIN</IDContext>
</Request>
```

Now I want to modify the input xml a little bit, so that the output would be like this:

```
<Instrument>
    <IdentifierType>ISIN</IdentifierType>
    <Identifier>XXX</Identifier>                            
    <Exchange>EX</Exchange>
</Instrument>
```

How should I modify the input xml file? Thank you!

Comment: Where do you retrieve the `Param` information? Written it the way you did like depicted above, Param should be an element in the `<Request>`... Is your sample input really representative of your data?

Comment: @potame Thank you for your comment. I am supposed to generate the input xml file so I have the freedom to have whatever it needs to get the desired output against the xslt file above. And yes my sample input is exactly what we feed to the xslt file currently. And of course it is a piece of code of a complete xml file. And I can put the needed data (possibly the `Param` ifnormation)  in anywhere of the input xml file (inside or outside of the `<Request>` element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT is currently looking for a `Param` element that is a child of the current `Request` element that is being matched. This means you would expect your XML to look like this:

```
<Request>
    <Identifier>XXX</Identifier>
    <IDContext>ISIN</IDContext>
    <Param Key='Exchange'>EX</Param>
</Request>
```

Having said that, this generates the following output:

```
<Instrument>
   <IdentifierType>ISIN</IdentifierType>
   <Identifier>XXX</Identifier>
   <UserDefinedIdentifier/>
   <Exchange>EX</Exchange>
</Instrument>
```

The template you have shown always creates a `UserDefinedIdentifier` for the `Request` element, regardless of whether a `UserDefinedIdentifier` element exists in the XML or not. The only way around this would be to change the XSLT to handle one not being present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The `UserDefinedIdnetifier` is not a problem to me so I didn't mention it. Since I knew little about xslt I thought both `Param` and `Key` were key words in xslt, not some random element/attribute that I define.